# how to select a drop-down of YouTube by IMacros + Auto Increment Value

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, youtube, imacros

This The Code that generated by iMacros.

The problem that, this didn't record the Selecting of the drop down

```
VERSION BUILD=8881205 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://www.youtube.com/channel_switcher?next=%2Faccount&feature=settings
TAG POS=2 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:Create<SP>a<SP>new<SP>channel
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:PlusPageName CONTENT=CH
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:TermsOfService CONTENT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:createaccount ATTR=ID:submitbutton
```

Also I Wanna Add an incremented number For The `'CH'>> CONTENT=CH`

Thanks In Advance For Your HELP :)